# Why do we use different image processing at train and test time for an image classification tasl

Tags: image-classification, image-preprocessing, data-augmentation

I would like to ask why we use different image processing at train and test for an image classification task. For example, this pytorch tutorial uses RandomResizedCrop at train time and then Resize + CenterCrop at test time.
[image: pytorch tutorial example]

I just read this paper called *Fixing the train-test resolution discrepancy* and it says this has been the best practice.
[image: Fixing the train-test resolution discrepancy]

However, I'm unable to figure out why nor find any documentation online as to why this is the case. Please help me shed some light on this. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

The key difference is that for training the preprocessing serves the purpose of data augmentation: it increases variance in the training data and thereby helps to better generalize. That is why you will find random cropping, flipping, rotating and zooming here.

But during inference that is not required and these random preprocessing steps would not be helpful. Therefore, you only do the preprocessing steps required  and eliminate randomness (e.g. crop images to the correct input size with centercrop instead of randomcrop).